# Url Routing with queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

With reference to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069515/url-routing-in-aspx), and [ScottGu's Documentation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx), I have successfullr routed a Url for my sites' Member profile page.

My page redirects `~/page/MemberName` to `~/page/Default.aspx`, which users the `MemberName` to request info.
This has worked fine until now.

I need a way to now allow a user to edit their data, and would like it to be accessed like `~/page/MemberName/Private`. The `Private` tag will tell the page the user can edit their content.

Comment: Can't you set up user roles and provide edit permission from that?

Comment: If you're using MVC you can set to your controlle action or class the DataAnnotation attribute [Authorize] read [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.authorizationattribute.authorize%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) and [Membership and Authorization](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7)

Comment: I'm using my own SQL based authorization, and will use that to reference data on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would consider doing what [@huMpty duMpty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925222/humpty-dumpty) suggests and using Roles for this.

You just need to set up your route to contain extra information in the URL.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("SalesRoute",
    "page/{MemberName}/{ExtraData}",
    "~/Default.aspx");
```

And then access it just like you would MemberName:

```
Page.RouteData.Values["ExtraData"];
```

If you want to make sure that *only* 'Private' is ever passed in you can add constraints to the route via one of the overloads.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("SalesRoute",
    "page/{MemberName}/{ExtraData}",
    "~/Default.aspx",
    false,
    new RouteValueDictionary(),
    new RouteValueDictionary{
       { "ExtraData", "[P|p]rivate" }
    });
```

It's worth noting that you may want to test this pretty well as you might end up with an overly strict routing rule.

Comment: I've changed the route to `routes.MapPageRoute("","Page/{address}/{data}","~/Page/Default.aspx");`, and added `string extraData = Page.RouteData.Values["data"].ToString();`.  
Now I get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` whenever I want to just go to /User/, and a `The resource cannot be found.` when I try go to /User/Private.